# Get data from mysql server and upload it into Sql server using Telerik openAcces ORM

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, telerik-open-access

I have this scenario: I am using Telerik OpenAccess ORM.

I have a MySql database with the following structure:

```
Products:  
    ID, VendorID,   [Product Name], MeasureID,  [Base Price]  
Vendors:  
    ID, [Vendor Name]  
Measures:  
    ID, [Measure Name]
```

And the same DB structure in SQL server. Is there a direct way I can tell OpenAccess to get the data from the MySQL DB and upload it into the SQL server DB, or do I have to do workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

You could follow this [help article](http://documentation.telerik.com/openaccess-orm/developers-guide/code-only-mapping/mapping-clr-types-properties-and-associations/advanced-mapping/backend-independent-mapping/fluent-mapping-mapping-clr-advanced-backend-independent-change-backend#changing_the_backend). It explains how to prepare a domain model, reuse it for different backends and switch between them during runtime.